# Understanding Poincaré lemma in one variable Griffith and Harris

Tags: complex-analysis

I would like to understand one little small detail in the proof. How come we end up with a factor of $\frac{-1}{\pi}$. I understand where the $-1$ came from, though I don't know what happened to the $2$. I understand everything else line by line.

> **$\bar\partial$-Poincaré Lemma in One Variable.** *Given $g(z)\in C^\infty(\bar\Delta)$, the function
> $$f(z)=\frac{1}{2\pi\sqrt{-1}}\int_\Delta\frac{g(w)}{w-z}dw\wedge d\bar w$$
> is defined and $C^\infty$ in $\Delta$ and satisfies*
> $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial\bar z}=g.$$
>
> ***Proof.*** For $z_0\in\Delta$ choose $\varepsilon$ such that the disc $\Delta(z_0,2\varepsilon)\subset\Delta$ and write
> $$g(z)=g_1(z)+g_2(z),$$
> where $g_1(z)$ vanishes outside $\Delta(z_0,2\varepsilon)$ and $g_2(z)$ vanishes inside $\Delta(z_0,\varepsilon)$. The integral
> $$f_2(z)=\frac{1}{2\pi\sqrt{-1}}\int_\Delta g_2(w)\frac{dw\wedge d\bar w}{w-z}$$
> is well-defined and $C^\infty$ for $z\in\Delta(z_0,\varepsilon)$; there we have
> $$\frac{\partial}{\partial\bar z}f_2(z)=\frac{1}{2\pi\sqrt{-1}}\int_\Delta\frac{\partial}{\partial\bar z}\left(\frac{g_2(w)}{w-z}\right)dw\wedge d\bar w=0.$$
> Since $g_1(z)$ has compact support, we can write
> \begin{align*}
> \frac{1}{2\pi\sqrt{-1}}\int_\Delta g_1(w)\frac{dw\wedge d\bar w}{w-z} & =\frac{1}{2\pi\sqrt{-1}}\int_\mathbb{C} g_1(w)\frac{dw\wedge d\bar w}{w-z}\\
> & =\frac{1}{2\pi\sqrt{-1}}\int_\mathbb{C} g_1(u+z)\frac{du\wedge d\bar u}{u},
> \end{align*}
> where $u=w-z$. Changing to polar coordinates $u=re^{i\theta}$ this integral becomes
> $$f_1(z)=-\frac{1}{\pi}\int_\mathbb{C}f_1(z+re^{i\theta})e^{-i\theta}dr\wedge d\theta,$$
> which is clearly defined and $C^\infty$ in $z$. Then
> \begin{align*}
> \frac{\partial f_1(z)}{\partial\bar z} & =-\frac{1}{\pi}\int_\mathbb{C}\frac{\partial g_1}{\partial\bar z}(z+re^{i\theta})e^{-i\theta}dr\wedge d\theta\\
> & =\frac{1}{2\pi\sqrt{-1}}\int_\Delta\frac{\partial g_1}{\partial\bar w}(w)\frac{dw\wedge d\bar w}{w-z};
> \end{align*}

Comment: Sorry for asking a naive question but why is this called the Poincare lemma? Isn't the Poincare lemma supposed to show that closed forms are locally exact? $g$ above isn't a $(0,1)$ form and it's not closed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $u = re^{i\theta}$, then $du = e^{i\theta}dr + ire^{i\theta}d\theta$, while $\bar{u} = re^{-i\theta}$ so $d\bar{u} = e^{-i\theta}dr - ire^{-i\theta}d\theta$. So

$$du\wedge d\bar{u} = (e^{i\theta}dr + ire^{i\theta}d\theta)\wedge (e^{-i\theta}dr - ire^{-i\theta}d\theta) = -irdr\wedge d\theta + ird\theta\wedge dr = -2irdr\wedge d\theta$$

and therefore $$\dfrac{1}{u}du\wedge d\bar{u} = \dfrac{-2ir}{re^{i\theta}}dr\wedge d\theta = -2ie^{-i\theta}dr\wedge d\theta.$$

This is why the coefficient $\dfrac{1}{2\pi i}$ in $g_1$ becomes $-\dfrac{1}{\pi}$ in $f_1$.

Comment: Thank you very much.